# How to find out what is making my cpu go crazy every time the screen shuts off?

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit

Every time my screen shuts off from inactivity my cpu fan starts spinning like there's no tomorrow.  When I move the mouse and the screen comes back on the fan immediately slows back down to normal speed, but I can't ever see signs of any unusual activity going on in the task manager.

I even left the task manager up so that if there were any activity going on I would be able to see it the moment I move the mouse... but I saw nothing.  So now I'm left wondering whether it might be possible that there's some process that regulates the fan speed that gets bypassed when the computer sleeps?

I would appreciate any clues that would lead me to shutting this noisy fan up.

Comment: Did you use the Task Managers Graph?  Check for a screensaver? Your sure it is the Cpu and not the GPU?  Folding or Seti at idle? Use any overclock tools? Speedfan type tools?

Comment: Autodefragger maybe?

Comment: @Psycogeek Just looked at processes tab so I will keep an eye on the graph next time.  No screensaver... power options are just set to turn display off after 15 minutes.  100% positive its the CPU fan.  Not sure what you mean by 'Folding or Seti at idle?'.  No tools of any kind.

Comment: @Amazed Yeah I thought about that too, but wasn't it.

Comment: @BrandonMoore Seti and folding, and others are programs that Can make use of an "idle computer", as a farmed out job from others. they can use 100%, chances are good you would know if you installed it.